# Old PHP project undeclared variables to PHP 7

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to update an old PHP project and I'm not really aware of PHP 4 and 5.
I don't fully understand what is going on in the snippet below..

`$page_num` isn't declared anywhere and I get **Notice: Undefined variable: page_num**. There's a lot of undefined variables in the code and multiple uses of `mysql_result` which is not supported in PHP 7.

PHP snippet:

```
if ($page_num) {
    $getpage_IDquery = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT page_ID FROM pages WHERE ID='$ID' AND page_num='$page_num' ORDER BY page_ID");
    if (mysql_num_rows($getpage_IDquery) > 0) {
        $page_ID = MYSQL_RESULT($getpage_IDquery,0,"page_ID");
    }
}
```

In the query (`SELECT page_ID FROM pages WHERE ID='$ID' AND page_num='$page_num' ORDER BY page_ID`) there are `$ID` and `$page_num` which, also, aren't defined anywhere in the code - not sure what is to be accomplished with it..

Table:

```
'pages' > ID, page_ID, picture, page_num;
```

Can anyone help me update the snippet to PHP7 using mysqli? What is mysql_result alternative?

Comment: Ummm... what exactly is the question here?

Comment: error_reporting(0); remove notice

Comment: Need help updating the snippet to PHP7 using mysqli

Comment: You are using the variable `$page_num` in the if condition, but it seems to be never have been declared or initialized before. it is not the query producing the error, it is the if-statement.

Comment: @MarkusZeller But do you have idea what is supposed to be pulled from the `pages` table with `ID=$ID` and `page_num='$page_num'` if neither is declared?

Comment: Try changing `if($page_num) ` to `if(isset($page_num))`. Also, you need to update your code using MYSQLi extension. PHP 7 does not support MYSQL Extension. Thast is deprecated.

Comment: If my answer solved your question, please mark as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the variable `$page_num` in the if condition, but it seems to be never have been declared or initialized before. It is not the query producing the error, it is the if-statement.

> I've altered the code to use PDO. You need to [create the connection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php), first.

```php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', $username, $password, $options);
```

You could add additional validation in the condition by doing

```php
if (!empty($page_num) && $page_num > 0) {
    $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT page_ID FROM pages WHERE ID=? AND page_num=? ORDER BY page_ID");
    $sth->execute([$ID, $page_num]);
    $page_ID = 0;
    if($sth->rowCount()) {
        $row = $sth->fetchObject();
        if ($row) $page_ID = $row->page_ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets rid of the undefined page_num error indeed. But another concern is that if I change query to mysqli: 

`$con = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db"); 

$getpage_IDquery = MYSQLI_QUERY($con,"SELECT page_ID FROM pages WHERE ID='$ID' AND page_num='$page_num' ORDER BY page_ID");`

I get `Notice: Undefined variable: ID and page_num`. How or what was to be accomplished with the old snippet if nothing was declared?

Comment: Updated with a link to on how to create the connection.

Comment: PHP is a quite "dirty" typeless language in the old versions. Now it is getting more typesafe, so it helps finding problems faster. The error always have been there, but without any notice.

Comment: Thankyou! Last question, if I have this same code but without `mysql_num_rows` such as:

`if ($page_num) {
    $getpage_IDquery = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT page_ID FROM pages WHERE ID='$ID' AND page_num='$page_num' ORDER BY page_ID");

        $page_ID = MYSQL_RESULT($getpage_IDquery,0,"page_ID");
}`

What would it be in PHP7? 
Sorry for so many questions.

Comment: You can use Rowcount on the executed statement. Answer updated.